# Why does pthread_setschedparam() produce EPERM on opensuse 11.4

Tags: linux, pthreads

I am writing an application with c++ and NetBeans on opensuse 11.4 with kernel 2.6.37.1-1.2
(logged in as root). This application creates a thread and when run gives this result:

```
    sched_param param;
    param.__sched_priority = -1;
    policy = SCHED_FIFO;
    param.__sched_priority = 50;
    result = pthread_setschedparam(m_thread,policy,&param);
```

result =  `1(EPERM (not permitted))`

Why?

Comment: Are you sure you're running it as root ?

Answer (score 3):

erm... because it is not permitted? Check the following settings:

> A non-privileged process cannot set the real-time
>   priority higher than its RLIMIT_RTPRIO setting. You can change this
>   with an "`rtprio`" entry in `/etc/security/limits.conf` (settings are
>   applied on login, so changes won't affect existing login sessions).
>
> Privilege is determined by the `CAP_SYS_NICE` capability.

Something like this should go in the config file:

```
domain       type    item     value
@group       soft    rtprio   100
```

The given group will have a soft rtprio limit to 100. 
This will work, assuming your PAM configuration uses pam_limits.

You may have to make sure of the hard limit too:

```
@group       hard    rtprio   100
```

Comment: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_getscheduler.2.html has all the details in the "Privileges and resource limits" section.

Comment: sry for the delay, My youngest experienced a sanitary mishap of the bigger kind, and as you know, _real life_ priorities somehow override _realtime_ priorities :) Have completed the edits now

Comment: it runs as root with SCHED_FIFO as periority.
i recreate fftw3.a with below configs:
 
 ./configure --enable-float  --enable-threads --with-combined-threads  --disable-fortran  --with-slow-timer  --enable-sse  --enable-sse2  --enable-avx

now avareage time is 0.4 ms !

but because i download fftw.lib i dont know its configs
wich is best configuration for maximum performance (with sse and no mpi)?