# How to solve assertion error in libopal?

Tags: c++, github, sip, opalvoip

I just wrote a script that calls a project I got from [github](https://github.com/tmakkonen/sipcmd) that calls a normal telephone number and during development I ran the script without a problem. But deploying it on my server and testing it there I get the following error message

```
Starting sipcmd
in debug mode
Manager
Init
initialising SIP endpoint...
TestChanAudio
TestChanAudio
Listening for SIP signalling on 0.0.0.0:5060
  assert.cxx(112)   PWLib   Assertion fail: Function pthread_setschedparam failed, file ptlib/unix/tlibthrd.cxx, line 745, Error=1
Assertion fail: Function pthread_setschedparam failed, file ptlib/unix/tlibthrd.cxx, line 745, Error=1

<A>bort, <C>ore dump, <T>hrow exception, <I>gnore?
```

Both machines are running linux and every single library is perfectly installed.
Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Hello did you successfully make a call to a phone number with sipcmd because I tried with opal 3.10.10 and opal 3.16.2 and it seems it doesn't detect answer nor hangup from remote part?

Comment: There is a fork with a fix for some of the crashes related to libopal, you can find it here https://github.com/stefanotorresi/sipcmd

Answer (score 0):

The error code is `EPERM` so according to the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html) the user running your application doesn't have permission to set the specified policy.

The policy only allows setting the scheduler priority so I guess the application is asking for a priority higher than the user is allowed to use? This question may hold some clues on how to fix this: [Why does pthread_setschedparam() produce EPERM on opensuse 11.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111302/why-does-pthread-setschedparam-produce-eperm-on-opensuse-11-4)

Comment: I'm running the script as root. How's it possible that root doesn't have the permission to change the priority?